# FOSUserBundle: Remove unique index for emailCanonical

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to remove the unique index on emailCanonical, so that multiple users can share the same email address. However, I do not want to edit FOS/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.xml directly as any updates to the bundle itself will remove the change. Is there any way I can override the emailCanonical field in my own bundle, while extending the base user (FOS/UserBundle/Model/User.php)

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Foo\BarBundle\Constant\SecurityConstant;

class User extends BaseUser {
    protected $id;
...
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to do this is to extend the `FOS\UserBundle\Model\User` class and then re-do all of the mapping (everything in `User.orm.xml`) yourself.

Sources:

- [Replacing the mapping of the bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md)
- FOSUserBundle [Issue #345](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/issues/345)

Comment: A better solution is the Tim's answer

Comment: Thanks @Arno - at the time of writing (~2011), this answer was correct since `@ORM\AttributeOverride` didn't exist. Anyone who comes across this question now should check out [@Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17059918/3765) below.

Answer (score 41):

The answer that is marked as right now (14 Oct 2014) is not the right answer at all.

This is the only right solution:

```
namespace XXX\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="User_User")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="usernameCanonical", errorPath="username", message="fos_user.username.already_used")
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="email", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true)),
 *      @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="emailCanonical", column=@ORM\Column(type="string", name="email_canonical", length=255, unique=false, nullable=true))
 * })
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
...
}
```

Also you need to override validation groups for your user form:

```
# app/config/config.yml
...
fos_user:
profile:
    form:
        validation_groups:  [Default] # Here you can also add your own groups if you have extra validation
registration:
    form:
        validation_groups:  [Default] # Here you can also add your own groups if you have extra validation
```

What did we do? We just overrode validation groups to not match the FOS default validations. Instead your form will be validated only with `Default` group. Described above validation `UniqueEntity` that doesn't have any group will be matched by `Default` group.

Comment: name="email_canonical", ... name="username_canonical" should do the job.

Comment: I modified the answer, add some more explanations. And now it works in any versions of Symfony and FOSUserBundle that are yet maintained.

Comment: Be carefull because only the first user will be able to reset it's password with the email.

Comment: This gives me an error: `Invalid field override named 'email'`. Somehow, `ClassMetadataInfo::fieldMappings` only contains the fields of the child class, and not the parent class (which contains the email field I want to override). This error is only thrown when generating entities.

Answer (score 1):

Supplement to Tim's answer, this is how you'd do it using YAML:

```
My\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: null
    repositoryClass: My\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository
    attributeOverride:
      usernameCanonical:
        unique: false
        name: usernameCanonical
        column: username_canonical
        length: 255
        nullable: false
        type: string
      emailCanonical:
        unique: false
        name: emailCanonical
        column: email_canonical
        length: 255
        nullable: false
        type: string
    fields:
        id:
          type: integer
          id: true
          generator:
              strategy: AUTO
        firstName:
          type: string
          length: 255
```