# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle User entity field override

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have a problem with overriding an entity. 
I need the field `emailCanonical` to be not be unique.

Here is what I've done:
In my `UserBundle\Resources\config\doctrine\User.orm.xml` I've added the following `attribute-overrides` configuration, according to the Doctrine2 documentation

```
<attribute-overrides>
    <attribute-override name="emailCanonical">
        <field column="email_canonical" unique="false" name="emailCanonical" />
    </attribute-override>
</attribute-overrides>
```

Then I ran the following console commands

```
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:diff
$ php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Everything worked fine. `emailCanonical` was made non unique.
But now, when I need to generate an entity in other bundles of project, I have a strange error:

```
 $ php app/console doctrine:generate:entities SkyModelsBundle:Category
 Generating entity "Sky\Bundle\ModelsBundle\Entity\Category"

 [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
 Invalid field override named 'emailCanonical' for class 'Sky\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User'.

 doctrine:generate:entities [--path="..."] [--no-backup] name
```

However, if I remove the override settings from xml mapping, everything works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure, what's your question.

Comment: Here's the way I solved it.. you can try this :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17059918/2342137

Comment: I have the same problem. I used annotations to override the same attribute and did not realize there was a problem until i tried using doctrine:generate:entities. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 13):

You override using PHP annotations like so (This is supported starting from doctrine version 2.3 and above, please note that in the documentation it mentions that you cannot override types , however I was able to do so using the latest version of doctrine , at the time of writing it is 2.4.4):

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\AttributeOverrides({
 *     @ORM\AttributeOverride(name="id",
 *          column=@ORM\Column(
 *              name     = "guest_id",
 *              type     = "integer",
 *              length   = 140
 *          )
 *      )
 * })
 */
class myUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

This is specified in the documentation at: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#overrides

Answer (score 3):

I believe the `name` attribute of the `field` tag is not required, since it is already specified for the `attribute-override` tag

Try this

```
<attribute-overrides>
    <attribute-override name="emailCanonical">
        <field column="email_canonical" unique="false" />
    </attribute-override>
</attribute-overrides>
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote from official [documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/doctrine.md#replacing-the-mapping-of-the-bundle), so may be its the only way.

> If you need to change the mapping (for instance to adapt the field
>   names to a legacy database), the only solution is to write the whole
>   mapping again without inheriting the mapping from the mapped
>   superclass.

Comment: It also say "Another solution can be through doctrine attribute and relations overrides"

Comment: Not so true since june /2013..
you can override only the mappings and still inherit from BaseUser. As I Outline here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718628/fosuserbundle-override-roles-property-roles-in-acme-demobundle-entity-user/24612877#24612877

Comment: You can by modifying the loaded metadata: http://blog.lavoie.sl/2015/01/symfony-override-doctrine-mapping.html

Comment: Nice hack @sebastien. Doctrine already has an answer to this issue http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override

Comment: This does not allow to modify indices, only fields. It works for this issue, yes, but by chance. If the unique was defined otherwise, it would not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that FOSUserBundle entities aren't imported correctly into your project.
Make sure FOSUserBundle is present in "mappings" section ("doctrine" branch) of your config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection:       default
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same bug just now, and I solved it. Doctrine throws this Mappingexception in ClassMetadataInfo when it cannot find the related property (attribute or relation) in its mapping.

So, in order to override "emailCanonical" attribute, you need to use "attribute-overrides" and "attribute-override" (as you did), and redefine php class property in your entity :

```
<?php
...
class YourUser extends BaseUser
{
    ...
    /**
     * Email canonical
     *
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email_canonical", type="string", length=255, unique=false)
     */
    protected $emailCanonical;
```

@EDIT : using this solution causes me another bug.

It solved the one about "Invalid field override named…", but I got another one with "Duplicate definition of column…" when trying to validate schema with `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate` command.

Any idea ?

Comment: I didn't find any other solution than explained above :/ I'm always looking for a "clean" solution for these bugs

Answer (score 0):

Your class that extends BaseUser  should be like this:

```
<?php 
namespace Namespace\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="your costum error message")
 *
 */
class myUser extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but i found a solution, at least it worked for me, maybe it would be helpful for someone else.

Well, i had the same issue and i'm using a custom manager for the fos_user, in the declaration file config.yml under doctrine entity_manager custom manager i declared the mapping to FOS_userBundle, BUT what was missing is to tell FOS_user that we use a diffrent manager and that's by adding :

fos_user:
----    db_driver: orm
----    **model_manager_name: MyCustom_Manager**